# Lint синтаксический анализатор

Tags: c, c++

нужно сгенерировать такую ошибку.

Too many #if levels. An internal limit was reached on the level of nesting of #if statements (including #ifdef and #ifndef).

Что тут имеется ввиду, какие ограничения по вложенности #if?

Comment: хм. попробуйте сгенерировать

    #ifdef TEST
    #ifdef TEST
    #ifdef TEST
    ... // 100 раз

    #endif
    #endif
    #endif
    ... // 100 раз

Comment: все норм и 150 тоже норм(

Comment: splint и 1000 переваривает :)

Comment: @fortunado, а исходники lint (кстати, какого?) о чем-нибудь таком не говорят?

В сообщениях splint (ubuntu) "internal limit " не нашел.

Comment: сделайте не 100, а `N` раз. генерируйте файл программно.

Answer (score 1):

Что-то не получается в комменте отформатировать.

```
klopp:~/garbage $cat test.h
#ifndef TEST
#include "test.h"
#endif
klopp:~/garbage $cat test.c
#include "test.h"
klopp:~/garbage $splint test.c
Splint 3.1.2 --- 03 May 2009
preprocessor: /home/klopp/garbage/test.h: macro or `#include' recursion too deep
Preprocessing error for file: /home/klopp/garbage/test.c
*** Cannot continue.
```

Comment: Понятно, не прокатила идея :(

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
// test.h
#ifndef __TEST_H_ // тут неважно что
#include "test.h"
#endif
```

Пытаемся рекурсивно #if в другой #if завернуть.
VS ругается так:

```
fatal error C1014: too many include files : depth = 1024
```

Но, может быть, Lint глупее.

Comment: вообще он не может завершится, выдает 2 повторяющихся вырнинга, и так без конца